# How to put an image in an AlertDialog? Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I don't know how to put an image into an AlertDialog.

I have this code, but i think this is not possible.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MessageDemo.this);    
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);    
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cw);             
alert.setView(imageView);    
alert.setNeutralButton("Here!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {

    }
});    
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Create one `sample.xml` and add `ImageView` in that XML.

**sample.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code :**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(MessageDemo.this);
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MessageDemo.this);
final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
alertadd.setView(view);
alertadd.setNeutralButton("Here!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {

                }
            });

alertadd.show();
```

Answer (score 44):

You could do it in the following way. This will show an alertDialog with a message (if you don't need the message, just remove that line) and the image (and an OK button):

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE_ID);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
        setMessage("Message above the image").
        setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {                     
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).
        setView(image);
builder.create().show();
```

Comment: How to move the message on bottom instead?

Comment: using positiveButton as bottom message

Comment: It worked, however it will crash on 2nd run with "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.". To avoid this, need to add code on setNegativeButton. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28071422/13299740

Answer (score 17):

**There is an another option you can put an image in AlertDialog without creating an xml file.**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.your image name);
    builder.setTitle("Incoming Call");
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Accept",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Reject",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

**For images I just do this:**

```
public void onClick (View view) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(R.layout.your_layout).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, i want to add the point that you should not be obliged to use AlertDialog. For example, in my case i want to show only imageView in a dialog and AlertDialog didn't worked for this case. The below solution worked for me :

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.myphoto_layout, null);
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(view);
dialog.show();
```

myphoto_layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/someImage" />
```

If you want to add image to your layout dynamically, you can use the below code :

```
ImageView iv = view.findViewById(R.id.iv); // id of your imageView element
iv.setImageBitmap(itmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
private void dialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenuActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View team = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null);
    alert.setView(team);
    alert.show();
}
```

In addition, implement a layout named `image_layout` and put the desired UI elements into it.

Answer (score 0):

**In kotlin**, just drag and drop a png file into "res" folder. In my case "res/drawable". Then, use this code:

```
    binding.myButton.setOnClickListener {
        val image = ImageView(requireContext()) 
        var myDialog: AlertDialog.Builder? = null
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_png_file)
        myDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(
            requireContext(),
            R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle
        )
        myDialog?.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialogTitle))
        myDialog?.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialogMessage))
        myDialog?.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.closeDialog)) { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        myDialog?.setView(image)
        myDialog?.show()
}
```

The png file should already contain margins, so that the image doesn't stretch to the edges of the dialog. I used photoshop to shrink the image and create the margins (margins are represented in red below):

[image]

Result (notice the left and right margins)

[image]