# Dynamic Pop-Up Menu Android Studio

Tags: java, android, image, popup, imageview

Is there a way to create a pop-up menu with just one imageview based a certain button clicked without using an XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the SE answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276501/how-to-put-an-image-in-an-alertdialog-android). A couple show sans-XML solutions.