# Show GIF using Glide in AlertDialog

Tags: android, imageview, android-alertdialog, gif, android-glide

I want to show GIF using Glide in ImageView, and set this ImageView in AlertDialog.

```
ImageView gifImageView = new ImageView(context);
Glide.with(context).load(recorder.getPictureFile()).asGif().into(gifImageView);

AlertDialog.Builder share_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
share_dialog.setMessage("Live Message Saved");
share_dialog.setPositiveButton("Done", null);
share_dialog.setView(gifImageView);
share_dialog.show();
```

But it only shows Message and PositiveButton.

[image]

I can't understand why, what should I do to fix it ?

## Update:2017/09/23

I create another project to test this issue, here is the code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button_main = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_main);
        imageView_main = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_main);

        GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewMainTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView_main);
        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.raw.test).into(imageViewMainTarget);

        button_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView gifImageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(gifImageView);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.raw.test).into(imageViewTarget);

                AlertDialog.Builder share_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                share_dialog.setMessage("GIF Test");
                share_dialog.setPositiveButton("Done", null);
                share_dialog.setView(gifImageView);
                share_dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

After running this project.

[image]

GIF can display in **imageView_main**, but it can't be shown on **AlertDialog's gifImageView** !

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, according to the answer of Niranj Patel.

[How to put an image in an AlertDialog?? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276501/how-to-put-an-image-in-an-alertdialog-android/6276592#6276592)

Here is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button_main = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_main);
        imageView_main = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_main);

        GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewMainTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView_main);
        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.raw.test).into(imageViewMainTarget);

        button_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
                ImageView gifImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview);

                GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(gifImageView);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.raw.test).into(imageViewTarget);

                AlertDialog.Builder share_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                share_dialog.setMessage("GIF Test");
                share_dialog.setPositiveButton("Done", null);
                share_dialog.setView(view);
                share_dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: and how is that different from the code i provided ? xD

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
ImageView gifImageView = new ImageView(context);

AlertDialog.Builder share_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
share_dialog.setMessage("Live Message Saved");
share_dialog.setPositiveButton("Done", null);
share_dialog.setView(gifImageView);
Glide.with(context).load(recorder.getPictureFile()).asGif().into(gifImageView);
share_dialog.show();
```

put your load GLIDE after setting the view.