# Cannot generate a Bitmap of a Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, android-relativelayout

I try to take a screenshot of the an entire `RelativeLayout` group of views and show it in an `AlertDialog` but the picture is black.

This is what the actual RelativeLayout looks like:

[image: The actual Relative Layout]

This is what I am getting in the dialog:

[image: The picture is black]

This is my code:

[image]

I learned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898412/9964100).

Comment: Please provide your code as text and not as a screenshot.

Comment: I think he tried but couldn't format the code correctly

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't format it correctly. That was why I did it that way.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted, it looks like you're just creating the `Bitmap` and not actually drawing anything into it. You can generate a bitmap of your view group by force-building the drawing cache of your view and pulling the image from the cache. Then, you should be able to add the `Bitmap` to your `ImageView`. See the example below:

```
viewGroup.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap viewGroupBitmap = viewGroup.getDrawingCache();

image.setImageBitmap(viewGroupBitmap);
```

Hope this helps.