# Android Load Full Image Recyclerview Cardview

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-recyclerview

The following is my recyclerview using php mysql and volley library in the attached image. As of now when one clicks the displayed image a toast of the image name appears as seen. Is it possible to load the full image click instead of the toast message?. Thank you in advance

[image]

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick = new ArrayList<>();

        ListOfdataAdapter = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManagerOfrecyclerView = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOfrecyclerView);

        JSON_HTTP_CALL();

        // Implementing Click Listener on RecyclerView.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    return true;
                }

            });
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                view = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if(view != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                    //Getting RecyclerView Clicked Item value.
                    RecyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

                    // Showing RecyclerView Clicked Item value using Toast.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Show a popup with that image instead of `toast`.

Comment: where you want to open full image in next activity or in same activity?

Comment: Thanks Md. Asaduzzaman. Exactly how?. @haresh in next activity. javaddroid kindly elaborate further

Answer (score 0):

extract full path of your image and put it in a variable, like this:

`http://yourserver.com/path/to/your/image.jpg`

then add an image loader library to your project like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

then you can load your image any where you need. like loading in an [alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6276592/2383176).

Comment: How do i do that sir?

Comment: as @haresh sayed before, where you want to show your image? and please get all of your activity code to help you for how to show that image.