# How to set ImageView in the AlterDialog Box

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-alertdialog

- I am fetching the `text` and `imageUrl` from `Firebase Realtime Database`. I want to show the `image` and then display the `text` in the `AlertDialogBox`.
- I am able to fetch the `text` and `imageUrl`. Able to set the text using `setTitle()` but when trying to display the `image`, not able to implement so.
- Referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276501/how-to-put-an-image-in-an-alertdialog-android) but there in they are using `drawable` or `static images`.
- Code

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(imageView)
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).create();

        dialog.show();
```

- Or just the `Text` using below code

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
        builder.setTitle("Explanation");
        builder.setMessage(list.get(position).getExplaination());
        url = list.get(position).getImageUrl();
        Log.i("URL", url);

        builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // dismiss dialog
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
```

- I have also created a `CustomDialogBox` view but not able to understand how should I pass the text and imageUrl value to that particular `AlertDialogBox.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CustomDialog">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eImageView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eTextView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:translationX="120dp"
        android:translationY="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To, set the image you need to get ImageView id from **CustomDialog** XML file and then you can set particular image into ImageView.

So, first of all, get your custom view using `getLayoutInflater()`.

**Note:** use one of the following as per your requirement.

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.CustomDialog, null); // for activity
View view = ((ViewHolder) holder).mainActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.CustomDialog, null); // for adapter class
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.CustomDialog, null); // for fragment
```

Then, add `view` into `builder.setView();`

```
builder.setView(view);
```

However, you also need to get ID of the all views which is located into your **CustomDialog** XML file.

```
TextView textview = view.findViewById(R.id.eTextView);
ImageView imageview = view.findViewById(R.id.eImageView);
```

Now, you can set your Image into **ImageView** Using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) dependency.

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageview);
```

Full example:

```
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.CustomDialog, null);
    ImageView imageview = view.findViewById(R.id.eImageView);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Explanation");
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setMessage(list.get(position).getExplaination());
    url = list.get(position).getImageUrl();
    Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageview);
    Log.i("URL", url);

    builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // dismiss dialog
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't set URL directly into Imageview for that you have to use these library

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Glide Example :

```
Glide.with(context).load(your_url).into(imageview);
```

Picass Example :

```
Picasso.get().load(your_url).into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user Dialog class. I'm writing the code below

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
ImageView imageView = dialog.findViewById(imageView); 
TextView textView = dialog.findViewById(textView); 
dialog.show();
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have also created a CustomDialogBox view but am not able to understand how should I pass the text and imageUrl value to that particular AlertDialogBox.

When you create a custom dialog class set a contractor with parameters for the text and image url. Use this text and imgUrl on your view. Use Picasso or Glide to load images from the online URL.

```
/*** On Activity class when you show your custom Dialog Box ****/

//Pass the text and img URL to your Custome Dialog constructor while create an instance
    DialogFragment dialogBox= new CustomDialogBox(text, ImgUrl); 
    dialogBox.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "custom_dialog_tag");

 // Custom DialogBox Class
 public class CustomDialogBox extends DialogFragment{
    private String text;
    private String imgUrl;
            
    //Constructor to receive argument from Activity    
    public CustomDialogBox (String text, String imgUrl) {
       this.text = text;
       this.imgUrl= imgUrl;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      // Get the layout inflater
      View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null); // for activity
    
       // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
       builder.setView(view)
       TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
       ImageView imgView= view.findViewById(R.id.yourImgView);

       // View online img with glide library
        Glide.with(context).load(imgUrl).into(imgView); 

        return builder.create();
       }
    }
```

To learn more about custom dialog - [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#CustomLayout)